# What causes an INVALID_TRANSACTION_START when submitting a transaction to Hedera

Tags: hedera-hashgraph, hashgraph

I am receiving the following error when I submit a transaction to Hedera:

```
failed precheck with status INVALID_TRANSACTION_START
```

This hasn't happened to me before and I'm confused.

Why is this error happening?

[image: screenshot of error described above]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INVALID_TRANSACTION_START is returned if your device clock is ahead of time. As transactions include the valid start time (it's in the TransactionId) in the payload the user signs, keeping the device synced with a time server (set date to auto) is the solution for now. The SDK removes a few seconds from the client's time to take into account minor time differences.

There have been suggestions of adding an API to Hedera enabling the query of a node's time and using this instead of the client's clock. The client would use the return value from the query to set its transaction id.
This could be an opportunity for a HIP.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and fixed it by making sure my timer was set to automatically update with the 2nd method below.

Method 1:

Follow the steps mentioned below.

Press Windows key + r and type services.msc and press enter.
Right click on Windows Time and select properties to check the status of the service.
Restart the Windows Time service.
Click on OK.
Restart the computer
Method 2:

a.       Click on clock and select “Change date and time settings”.

b.      Click on the “Internet Time” tab.

c.       Check if it is set to “synchronize the time with time.windows.com”

d.      If the option is selected, click on change settings to check the option “Synchronize with an Internet Time server”

e.      Click on OK.

Method 3:

Follow the steps mentioned below.

Press Windows key + X and select Command prompt(Admin).

Type each one of the command below and press enter.

net stop w32time

w32tm /unregister

w32tm /register

net start w32time

w32tm /resync

Restart the computer to test the issue again.

W32tm.exe is used to configure Windows Time service settings. It can also be used to diagnose problems with the time service. W32tm.exe is the preferred command line tool for configuring, monitoring, or troubleshooting the Windows Time service.